# I need getRTF() example for win32 api richedit control

Tags: winapi, richedit

I saw in MSDN  that `Rich edit` control Win 32 `API` have function to get rich text format that its contents.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa247997%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

But in MSDN  have no example so that I don't know how to use this function. I need get text in `Rich Edit` with full rich text format as a string. Please help me. Thanks so much.

Comment: You're looking at the docs for Java in a fifteen year old version of Visual Studio.  [This might be more useful.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb774304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I know about EM_STREAMIN and EM_STREAMOUT. But, these messsage are get and set direct from file *.rtf . I need get rtf of Rich edit as a string without use file.

Comment: The messages work with the raw data.  You can write it to a file or put it in a string.  It's your choice.